# How to connect points in python plot?

Tags: python

Wanted to connect points in matplotlib plot.below is the sample code. each element in list has timestamp and argv. Please educate.Code below plots correctly but do not connect points between different elements of list even if I have mentioned 'rs-'.

```
for a in list:
      plt.plot(a.time,a.argv,'rs-')
```

Comment: The code works fine for me; it creates a line with the points connected. Do you want to connect points *in between* different elements of `list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your points connected, you need to plot them all in one call. Create a list of the points you want to plot, then call `plt.plot`

```
points = [(a.time, a.argv) for a in l]
plt.plot(points, "rs-")
```